# SPFx SharePoint 2016 on premise - Issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx

I've installed **Feature Pack 2** and developed simple "**HelloworldwebPart**".

I created two sites in my WebApp
Example :

**Team Site :** `https://<Domain>/Sites/Test`

**App Catalog :** `https://<Domain>/Apps/Catalogs`

Upload the SPFx webpart to App catalog site -- no error and issue.

Didn't see apps when I try to add the Webpart to main site
 (`https://<Domain>/Sites/Test`  >> **Site content** >> **Add an apps**).

Any Suggestions please ?

Comment: Have you verified in the app catalog that the solution package doesn't contain any errors and has been deployed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the [full setup for apps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx) in your on-premises farm? At a high level, this includes:

- Creating the forward lookup zone and CNAME alias in DNS
- Configuring the Subscription Settings and App Management service applications
- Setting up app URLs in Central Administration

If so, have you also granted access to the App Catalog to the user who is attempting to add the app and can't currently see it?

Comment: I've completed the setup and user has permission but still unable to see the apps.

Comment: hello @user70602, did this issue ever get resolved? we are facing similar issue on customer env although it is for traditional SharePoint provided hosted app on SP 2016 SP2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have to do to see the webpart. Uses a keyword which returns noly your webpart, it will return something like below,

*We didn't find a match here, but check out the SharePoint Store.*

We didn't find a match here, but search across all your apps.

Click on "Search across all your apps". You will see your app.

However, I can't add it. It says "Sorry, apps are turned off. If you know who runs the server, tell them to enable apps."
Do I really need to install App service? SPFx is not running on App domain, it runs on page's context.

Answer (score 0):

SPFX webparts don't need full setup of apps! Just type in a fictional URL in the app URL's central administration section and wait a few moments.